# SalesAgreementProductSchedule Database.update fail if ID field not first Field in SObject

Tags: apex, remote-action

We use Salesforce Manufacturing Cloud for our business. We create a VF page show SalesAgreementProductSchedule record and edit those records.

To get and update records, we use JavaScript Remoting.During test, we found follow weird behavior in Salesfoce.

If we send SalesAgreementProductSchedule like { PlannedQuantity: 48, ID: 0YC8b0000008SDiGAM }, Salesforce Database.update throw error and we can not update this record. But if we put ID at first field in record like { ID: 0YC8b0000008SDiGAM, PlannedQuantity: 48 } we can success update this record.

I want to ask you why cause this behavior? Is there any document about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found solution base on Salesforce document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm

In this document has follow content:
[image]

So we change our code as follow:

```
if (hasId) {
    newSObject(id);
} else { 
    newSObject();
}
```